# Add several Spectral Indexes over an image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, vegetation-index

I want to add several spectral indexes in one go over a Sentinel2 TOA collection.
If I do only with NDVI the script works. If I add 2 types of NDWI I get the following
"Syntax Error: Unespected token (61:4)"
Please see below the script I am using

````
// First define an area of interest
var lat = 65.64; 
var lng = 34.35;
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(lat, lng); 
//var aoi = point.buffer(100000); // Create an area (1km buffer around point)
var country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'AF'));
var aoi = country;

Map.setCenter(lat, lng, 5); // Center the map on this location, zoom level 10

var start = '2019-03-29'; // initial date of the image collection
var end = '2019-05-05'; //final date of the image collection

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}


// reduce NDVI over an image collection
// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

// reduce NDWI (1-2) over an image collection
// Function to calculate and add an NDWI (1-2) bands

var addNDWI1 = function(image) {
  var ndwi1 = image.normalizedDifference(['B8A', 'B11']).rename('NDWI1');
  return image.addBands(ndwi1);
};

var addNDWI2 = function(image) {
  var ndwi2 = image.normalizedDifference(['B8A', 'B12']).rename('NDWI2');
  return image.addBands(ndwi2);
};
// Download the Sentinel-2 imagery collection
var imgs = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate(start, end)
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .map(addNDVI);
    .map(addNDWI1);
    .map(addNDWI2);
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one semicolon at the end when you are applying map several times. Just remove the others:

```
// Download the Sentinel-2 imagery collection
var imgs = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate(start, end)
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .map(addNDVI)
    .map(addNDWI1)
    .map(addNDWI2);
```